# OnClick button Get from database and display on a input field live

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to input some text on a input field and on `click` the button it should display data from mysql on another input field name `autofiller`.

```
$(function () {
  $('#button').on('click', function () {
    var text = $('#fromInput');
    $.ajax({
      url:"serv.php",
      method: "GET",
      data: {
        "id": text
      },
      success: function(data) {
        var name=JSON.parse(data);
        document.getElementsByClassName("autofiller").value=name.name;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

HTML form

```
<form id="sampleForm">
 <input type="text" id="fromInput" />
 <input type="text" class="autofiller"/>

 <input type="button" value="button" id="button">
```

This is my back-end php script-->

```
<?php
    $link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","employee");



    $data=$_GET["id"];

  $result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM user where userid='$data'");

  header('Content-type:application/json');
  exit(json_encode($result));
 ?>
```

Comment: What error you are getting here?

Comment: i am not getting the result. no error shown

Comment: alert the data in your ajax success function to check if you are even getting something.

Comment: With SELECT * you have a good chance to send over the password of the user as well. Also read about SQL INJECTIONS IN MYSQL

Answer (score 1):

**I hope this would help you to solve**

```
$(function () {
 $('#button').on('click', function () {
    var text = $('#fromInput');
    $.ajax({
      url:"serv.php",
      method: "GET",
      data: {
        "id": text
      },
      success: function(data) {
        var name=JSON.parse(data);
        $(".autofiller").val(name.name);// Try this 
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this:

```
 var text = $('#fromInput').val();
```

**Update**

There are many bugs in your code, as below:

**In Backend**

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM user where userid='$data'");
```

This does not return the data as you expect, you have to use **mysql_fetch_array** to fetch the data from the result which can be something like this:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM users where id='$data'";
 $result = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link,$sql));
```

**In frontend**
 You don't need to parse the data to JSON as you are already sending the response with a JSON data:

```
 var name=JSON.parse(data);
```

Instead you can do something like this:

```
 document.getElementById("autofiller").value=data.name;
```

Notice here, Using id instead of class is a better approach, as you would want to set the value to a specific input, not a group of inputs, so you might have to add an id to autofiller like this

```
<input type="text" class="autofiller" id="autofiller"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but it didn't worked either. I have updated my post with my back-end php script.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("autofiller")[0].value=name.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `getElementById()` to get the single element reference because `getElementByClassName()` will return an array of reference of elements with that class name.

try this

```
document.getElementById("autofiller").value=name.name;
```

where autofiller should be the "id" instead of class

in HTML

```
<input type="text" id="autofiller"/>
```

Comment: Didn't worked. This is my backend php script ---->  <?php
    $link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","employee");


   
    $data=$_GET["id"];
   
    $result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM user where userid='$data'");
 
  header('Content-type:application/json');
   exit(json_encode($result));
?>